# Shapely issue with parallel offset: cant extend coastline past 1000m

Tags: python, shapely

Im trying to extend the USA coastline out 100km to take a salinity measurement. Im using the census coastline file from https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2021&layergroup=Coastline

When I use shapely parallel offset at 1000 (in utm coords) it works. When I try with 10000 Ι get the following error:

```
TopologyException: assigned depths do not match at 5035602.143929367 6813072.2019115007
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/n5/_2d3c5sd5j3810327mknn0sh0000gn/T/ipykernel_74111/723695200.py in <module>
----> 1 geoms = [x.parallel_offset(10000) for x in usa.geometry.to_crs(utm)]

/var/folders/n5/_2d3c5sd5j3810327mknn0sh0000gn/T/ipykernel_74111/723695200.py in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 geoms = [x.parallel_offset(10000) for x in usa.geometry.to_crs(utm)]

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py in parallel_offset(self, distance, side, resolution, join_style, mitre_limit)
    173                 'Cannot compute offset from zero-length line segment')
    174         try:
--> 175             return geom_factory(self.impl['parallel_offset'](
    176                 self, distance, resolution, join_style, mitre_limit, side))
    177         except OSError:

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/geo_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py in geom_factory(g, parent)
     71     # Abstract geometry factory for use with topological methods below
     72     if not g:
---> 73         raise ValueError("No Shapely geometry can be created from null value")
     74     ob = BaseGeometry()
     75     geom_type = geometry_type_name(g)

ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value
```

I assume its a clash of points of some kind?
Code used:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd 
from shapely.geometry import Point, box
import shapely as sh 
import geopandas as gpd 
import pyproj

coast_path='/Users/gracecolverd/data/tl_2021_us_coastline/tl_2021_us_coastline.shp'
coast = gpd.read_file(coast_path)

bbox = [box(24.9493,49.5904,-125.0011,-66.9326)]
bbox = gpd.GeoDataFrame( geometry=bbox, crs= 'EPSG:4326')
coast=coast.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
usa = coast.sjoin(bbox)


utm = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:26907')
geoms = [x.parallel_offset(10000) for x in usa.geometry.to_crs(utm)]
```

Comment: What's `sjoin`? Is that a typo?

Comment: spatial join from geopandas - takes all of the lines within the bounding box (usa coords)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I upgraded my geopandas version and I have it now

Comment: Not an expert but I would guess that once you move it that far it's outside the UTM zone (7N, for EPSG 26907)? Anyhow I recommend asking on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that this was an issue with extending outside the UTM zone as @josh Friedlander mentioned

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33514929)